# Is it OK to consult community against suspected Drupal bugs?

Tags: support, questions

I mean situations where I am pretty sure I found a bug in core or a contributed module, but I want to get confirmation before I file an issue to the project or apply a time-costly workaround.

While such a Q & A might not be a real value for the Drupal Answers archives, it would certainly be of a great value for me and possibly to others (perhaps too shy to ask).

Also, we have to take into account that module developers overwhelmed with their work, often respond after quite a while (if at all). Therefore having a quick response would be a great help.

Comment: "but I want to get confirmation before I file an issue to the project"

The issue queue can give you that confirmation. It's what it's meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a too localized situation, to me.
The question doesn't probably help any future readers, considering the fact the question is asked to get confirmation about a bug. If there is a bug that is then reported, and resolved, future readers would not get useful information from the question.

If the question is similar to the following one, then it would probably be an acceptable question. (It could be not acceptable, if the description of the task is too generic.)

> I am trying to achieve this task, but so far I am not successful. [Description of the task]
>
> What am I doing wrong?

For such question, the answer could be:

- The OP is doing something wrong.
- The OP is not doing anything wrong; it's just an obscure consequence of a bug in a module, or Drupal.

Clearly, if the question is about a PHP error raised from a module, the question is off-topic.

Once you know it's a bug, the question is off-topic on *Drupal Answers*. Somebody could also argue that it is not a question, but a request of confirming a bug.